# Route displays a duplicate form

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-components

I started a project in angular2 but for whatever reason, my route display my component two times. Here is related code snippet.

*app.routing.ts*

```js
// Some import 
import { AuthComponent } from './master/auth';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'master/registration',
    component: AuthComponent
  }
];
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

*app.module.ts*

```js
import { AuthComponent } from './master/auth/auth.component';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { routing } from './app.routing';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    // components
    AuthComponent
 ],
 providers: [
 // some providers
 ],
 imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    routing
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

*app.component.html* contains `<app-auth></app-auth>`

*auth.component.ts*

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as all from './auth-utils';
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-auth',
  templateUrl: 'auth.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['auth.component.css']
})
export class AuthComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

*auth.component.html*

```html
<app-register-form [fields]="fields"></app-register-form>
<app-login-form [loginFields]="loginFields"></app-login-form>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: what location do you have when component duplicates? as I understood `auth` duplicates?

Comment: @Mikki component duplicates when my location is `/master/registration` and also the component is displayed when the location is `/` with an error because I don't have any routes for `/`

Comment: auth component duplicates?

Comment: @Mikki yes I have two `app-auth` inside the `app-root`. One before  `router-outlet` and one after

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks to me like you are including your `AuthComponent` directly in your template using its selector `<app-auth></app-auth>` **and** routing to it so it appears in your `<router-outlet>`. You just want to do one or the other.

Since you are trying to route to `AuthComponent`, remove `<app-auth></app-auth>` from your template. In fact, since `AuthComponent` is a routing target, it doesn't need a selector at all, so you may remove some confusion by deleting the line from its component annotation:

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  /* selector: 'app-auth', */
  templateUrl: 'auth.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['auth.component.css']
})
export class AuthComponent...
```

Comment: I removed `<app-auth><app-auth>` and added `<router-outlet>` to `app.component.html`  and it works. One quick question: Is there a way to display only `app-register-form` in my `auth.component.html` using routing and without removing `app-login-form`?

Comment: Yes, you can route to your `app-register-form` and have it rendered in a `<router-outlet>` in your `auth.component.html`, while still having your `app-login-form` component rendered using its selector.

Comment: If you mean you want to *hide* `app-login-form` while your `app-register-form` route is active, you could do that using `<app-login-form *ngIf="someConditionalProperty"...>`

Answer (score 3):

You mentioned that you already have `<app-auth>` in your `app.component.html`, thats gives you first instance of `auth` component, and you have `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` inside of your `auth.component.html` that is your second instance.